# How to create dynamic links in nuxt for each available language?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

For my project I'm using Nuxt with i18n. In the .env file I've created an array with all available languages. Now in nuxt.config I'd like to configure the about menu for each available language. The about should be an object, holding the locale and the menu name, so i.e.:

```
about: {
  "nl-NL": process.env.ABOUT_NAME[0],
  en: process.env.ABOUT_NAME[1]
}
```

I don't want the available languages be hardcoded, they should be dynamic. So for each language in AVAILABLE_LOCALE.split(",") add property to the about object.

How can I achieve this? Right now I have this code:

***nuxt.config.js***

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  ABOUT: Array.from(process.env.ABOUT_NAME).forEach(lang => {
    this.language = lang;
  }),
}
```

***.env***

```
AVAILABLE_LOCALE='nl-NL,en,es'
ABOUT_NAME='Over ons,About us,Sobre nosotros'
```

Comment: do you want your route like this: `/:lang/users` and `/users`(use default language)?

Comment: yes please, thats should be the markup. Just the word 'users' can differ, depending on the locale. So if english is default: /users || /nl/gebruikers || /es/usarios

Comment: You can use @nuxtjs/i18n (https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/routing/)

Comment: @BTL I am using i18n, I'm looking for a way to rewrite the url names, specific for the chosen language. I don't want the languages and names hardcoded in nuxt.config. Those are set in .env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! This is the result that works for me:

```
    PAGE: {
      NAME: JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          process.env.PAGE_NAME.split(",")
            .map(function(translation) {
              const index = process.env.PAGE_NAME.split(",").indexOf(
                translation
              );
              let newObject = {};
              newObject.id = index;
              newObject.language = process.env.AVAILABLE_LOCALE.split(",")[
                index
              ];
              newObject.name = translation;
              return newObject;
            })
            .reduce((acc, obj) => {
              let { name, language } = obj;
              return { ...acc, [language.toUpperCase()]: name };
            }, {})
        )
      ),
      URL: JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          process.env.PAGE_NAME.split(",")
            .map(function(translation) {
              const index = process.env.PAGE_NAME.split(",").indexOf(
                translation
              );
              let newObject = {};
              newObject.id = index;
              newObject.language = process.env.AVAILABLE_LOCALE.split(",")[
                index
              ];
              newObject.name = translation;
              return newObject;
            })
            .reduce((acc, obj) => {
              let { name, language } = obj;
              return {
                ...acc,
                [language.toUpperCase()]: name
                  .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
                  .toLowerCase()
              };
            }, {})
        )
      )
    },
```